# Отвалились сниппеты в Modx

Tags: cms, modx, revo

Вообще перестали вызываться сниппеты из шаблонов. Даже простейшие типа echo 11; не отрабатывают. Где стоить копать и куда? Как обрабатываются сниппеты в шаблонах?

Comment: Попробуйте руками удалить всё содержимое из директории `/core/cache/`

Comment: и то, что в журнале ошибок добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: В логах ничего, только ошибки за сутки до этого были. Ворнинг про тайм зону, подробностей не помню.

Comment: Развернул сайт на локале, опять создал тестовый сниппет, несколько раз почистил кеш и вроде заработало. Но не понял почему. Если из-за кеша, то почему после первой очистки кеша не заработало.

Comment: С подобным столкнулся, когда выполнялся сниппет по `cron'у` от `root'а`. В результате, modx не мог переписать созданный рутом кэш и сайт "падал".